# Turtle graphics problems

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I was trying to make a game similar to snake using turtle graphics.
I added the line wn.update, but every time it's just saying en error, and if I remove it, it just crashes.
Does anybody know why?

I am pretty nooby in python so I might have a really dumb mistake

```
import turtle
import random

score = 0

def go_up():
    if cat.direction != "down":
        cat.direction = "up"

def go_down():
    if cat.direction != "up":
        cat.direction = "down"

def go_left():
    if cat.direction != "right":
        cat.direction = "left"

def go_right():
    if cat.direction != "left":
        cat.direction = "right"

def move():
    if cat.direction == "up":
        y = cat.ycor()
        cat.sety(y + 20)

    if cat.direction == "down":
        y = cat.ycor()
        cat.sety(y - 20)

    if cat.direction == "left":
        x = cat.xcor()
        cat.setx(x - 20)

    if cat.direction == "right":
        x = cat.xcor()
        cat.setx(x + 20)

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.setup(width =600,height= 600)
wn.tracer(0)

mouse=turtle.Turtle()
mouse.penup()
mouse.goto(0,100)

cat = turtle.Turtle()
cat.penup()

while True:
    wn.update()
    if cat.distance(mouse) < 20:
        x = random.randint(0, 500)
        y = random.randint(0, 500)
        mouse.goto(x, y)

wn.onkeypress(go_up, "w")
wn.onkeypress(go_down, "s")
wn.onkeypress(go_left, "a")
wn.onkeypress(go_right, "d")
wn.listen()

wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did it crash or just gave an error?

Comment: If it gave an error than which error?

Comment: @JonathanDrukker
It gave an error, and it crashed if I removed the line. The error was:
`File "C:/Users/avner/PycharmProjects/CatAndMouse/main.py", line 52, in <module>
    wn.update()
  File "C:\Users\avner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\turtle.py", line 1304, in update
    t._update_data()
  File "C:\Users\avner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\turtle.py", line 2647, in _update_data
    self.screen._incrementudc()
  File "C:\Users\avner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\turtle.py", line 1293, in _incrementudc
    raise Terminator
turtle.Terminator`

Answer (score 0):

Your program isn't structured properly.  You shouldn't have a `while True:` in an event-driven would like turtle.  (And particularly not before additional statements you need to execute!)  You shouldn't implement `tracer()` and `update()` until you have your program basically working.  Here's a rework of your code that is "playable":

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def go_up():
    if cat.direction != 'down':
        cat.direction = 'up'
        cat.setheading(90)
        screen.update()

def go_down():
    if cat.direction != 'up':
        cat.direction = 'down'
        cat.setheading(270)
        screen.update()

def go_left():
    if cat.direction != 'right':
        cat.direction = 'left'
        cat.setheading(180)
        screen.update()

def go_right():
    if cat.direction != 'left':
        cat.direction = 'right'
        cat.setheading(0)
        screen.update()

def move():
    cat.forward(20)

    if cat.distance(mouse) < CURSOR_SIZE:
        x = randint(CURSOR_SIZE - 300, 300 - CURSOR_SIZE)
        y = randint(CURSOR_SIZE - 300, 300 - CURSOR_SIZE)
        mouse.goto(x, y)

    screen.update()

    screen.ontimer(move, 200)  # 1/5 second delay in milliseconds

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.tracer(False)

mouse = Turtle('turtle')
mouse.penup()
mouse.sety(100)

cat = Turtle('arrow')
cat.penup()
cat.direction = 'right'  # user defined property

screen.onkeypress(go_up, 'w')
screen.onkeypress(go_down, 's')
screen.onkeypress(go_left, 'a')
screen.onkeypress(go_right, 'd')
screen.listen()

move()

screen.mainloop()
```